# Pandas: Filter a column by the value from applying a function to another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

Suppose I have a df with 2 columns A and B and a class Foo() which can be instantiated by A's value. I'd like to get a unique series of B which satisfy Foo(A).item.price == 0.
I tried the following code which obviously doesn't work.

```
unique_B = df.loc[Foo(df.A.str).item.price == 0, "B"].unique()
```

I guess I could create a third column to store the value of foo(df.A), is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.A.apply(foo)` instead of `foo(df.A.str)`:

```
unique_B = df.loc[df.A.apply(foo) == 0, "B"].unique()
```

To access the `item` property of the `foo` class:

```
unique_B = df.loc[df.A.apply(lambda x: foo(x).item.price) == 0, "B"].unique()
```

Comment: Sorry I was missing some details in the original question (now updated). I actually need to access some attributes from what foo returns. Can I do "unique_B = df.loc[df.A.apply(Foo).item.price == 0, "B"].unique()"?

Comment: Does `foo` return a dict?

Comment: `foo` is actually a class. I need to instantiate it with A's value, then access the `item` property which is an object, and then access item's price property.

Comment: Okay, then check now.